# Why am I getting error CS0116 when building using a .rsp file?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, csc

I'm trying to build a project using an csc.exe and a .rsp file, but I keep getting an error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.  To troubleshoot, I made the simplest program ever...

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

From the command line, I run the command

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" Test.rsp
```

Test.rsp looks like this

```
/nologo
/target:exe
/platform:x86
/out:"Test.exe"
"Test.cs"
```

---

If I compile Test.cs directly, I don't get this error.  For example, if I run this command at the command line...

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /target:exe /platform:x86 /out:"Test.exe" "Test.cs"
```

The "Program" is created successfully.

So why is compiling using a .rsp file causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is trying to interpret the file as C#. If you want to use a response file, you need to let the compiler know it's a build file and not a code file. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/response-file-compiler-option):

> The @ option lets you specify a file that contains compiler options and source code files to compile

For example:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" @Test.rsp
```